# view files inside public, is it BIG security risk?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am looking at a laravel theme package that stores the themes with assets and views inside public folder. This package is developed by a laravel pro so I wonder why he decided to store view files of the theme inside public folder? Some other theme packages split theme between public and resources/views folder.

If I use this package, which has nice features, what could happen to my website? Could it easily get exploited or hacked if view files are inside public folder? Is there 100% way to secure the website that has view files in public folder? What is that way?

Can you give me your opinion and some examples what could happen with this approach?

Answer (score 0):

IMO this is kind of rubbish. It let any user see your views. There shouldn't be any logic in those, but it can.

Also, `/public` isn't the right place to store view. They should be in `/resources/view` therefor in dont see any reason why they shouldn't be in the right directory

Comment: nobody is talking about perhaps using .htaccess to prevent viewing of these blade files, is that an option and if it is, then its secure right?

Answer (score 0):

of course it is .. it's like telling the whole world that `"hey this is my php script"`.. this is not the proper way of doing such so..

Comment: Hello you :3
It shouldn't be a major security risk because (normally) there is no logic inside views, only templating which similar of an angular webapp for example : Not a real problem, not a ideal solution

Comment: Templating isn't logic. I know there may is some loops and IFs but that's it. No sanitization, no treatment, no queries, etc

Comment: nobody is talking about perhaps using .htaccess to prevent viewing of these blade files, is that an option and if it is, then its secure right?